# Lotus Notes - @Transform - Workaround available for XPages?

Tags: xpages, lotus

I'm currently migrating a Lotus Notes application to XPages. The application contains several formulas which use "@Transform" and as there is no SSJS equivalent for "@Transform", I'm wondering how best to code these formulas in XPages. At the moment I'm trying using session.evaluate. Is this the best option or is there another method which someone could recommend?

Answer (score 3):

`session.evaluate` is handy if you have existing @Formula code. In SSJS you can use:

```
for (var i in array_variable) {
  print(array_variable[i]);
}
```

or

```
for (var element in vector_or_list) {
  print(element);
}
```

Comment: I have used this approach too. Convert your @Transform logic into SJSS where you use a loop instead.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this but I have quite a few @Transform formulas in a legacy application that I am migrating to XPages so I am afraid that this approach will require a lot of coding.

Comment: I got it working using: var tmpVar1 = @Replace(tmpVar, @Word(r5,"#",3), @Word(r5,"#",1));

var ids = new Array();
for (var i in tmpVar1) {
  ids[i] = @If(@Length(tmpVar1[i]) > 1,tmpVar1[i],"(empty)");
} - much easier than using session.evaluate (see comment below)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using session.evaluate() as you are trying to do currently.

Since you write "trying" - do you have any issues with this? If you use this functionality in several places I would recommend creating a custom Java class to handle the evaluate (and ensure proper input). It can easily be called from your SSJS - and it would make a fine candidate for an XSnippet or an extension to the Extension Library ;-)

/John

Comment: Thanks. I have an SSJS formula - var tmpVar1 = @Replace(tmpVar, @Word(r5,"#",3), @Word(r5,"#",1)); - which gives the following result: BDBF5A50E76DCDEDC1257AC5004C0188,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0            I add this to session.evaluate with the following code:                   var eval = session.evaluate("@Transform("+tmpVar1+";@If(@Length(entry)>1;entry;\"(empty)\"))");                                                             however, this causes Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Hardcoding - var eval = session.evaluate("List:=\"BDBF5A50E76DCDEDC1257AC5004C0188\":\"2\":\"3\":\"4\":\"5\":\"6\":\"7\";@Transform(List;\"entry\";@If(@Length(entry)>3;entry;\"(empty)\"))");
eval - does work and gives the expected result.

Comment: I think you answered your question. For formula to understand it as list you need to convert your result to that format. It's probably easier not to use formula when you already have an SSJS array.

Comment: I have tried converting theSSJS variable to the correct format using - var tmpVar2:string = @Implode(tmpVar1,":");
var tmpVar3 = '"' + @ReplaceSubstring(tmpVar2,":",'":"') + '"'; - but it gives me a 500 error. tmpVar3 in this case is equal to - "BDBF5A50E76DCDEDC1257AC5004C0188":"2":"3":"4":"5":"6":"7" - which I believe to be the correct format?

Comment: Have you tried putting your string to be evaluated to one variable and printing it out? You can then place it to formula editor to make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Panu, thank you so much! I did as you suggested and noticed that the @Transform formula had a parameter missing. I corrected it to - var tmpVar1 = @Replace(tmpVar, @Word(r5,"#",3), @Word(r5,"#",1));
var tmpVar2:string = @Implode(tmpVar1,":");
var tmpVar3 = '"' + @ReplaceSubstring(tmpVar2,":",'":"') + '"';
tmpVar4 = "@Transform("+tmpVar3+";\"entry\";@If(@Length(entry)>1;entry;\"(empty)\"))";
var eval = session.evaluate(tmpVar4); - and now it works as expected. Fantastic!

Comment: you can make your life easier - don't escape double quotes in formula and use single quote/apostrophe for delimiting formula string. eg.: 'tmp := "1";'

Comment: Thanks Frantisek, a very useful tip!

Comment: Hi Tony - sorry that I did not return to you before... I agree with Panu and Frantisek ;-)
One tip more I would give you is to use a text field in a form (standard Notes) - paste the formula that you printed as suggested by Panu - and then press Shift+F9 --> this evaluates the formula ;-) 
That is an easy way to verify your formula to eliminate this as a cause of failure.
/John